# How to Inherit Attributes in Python

Tags: python, inheritance

Why does it print 0 and not 24?
Also, why does it bring up an error if I dont explicitly define num in the System class even though im doing it in the constructor?

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
class System(ABC):

    num = 0

    def __init__(self, input):
        self.num = input
        return

    @abstractmethod
    def getNum(self):
        pass

class FirstSystem(System):
    def __init__(self, input):
        super().__init__(input)
        return

    def getNum(self):
        return super().num

foo = FirstSystem(24)
print(foo.getNum())
```

Comment: You probably don't want both a class attribute and an instance attribute with the same name (`num`) in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I didnt even know there was a difference between the two!

Comment: Sidenote: `input` is a bad variable name since it [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the [builtin `input` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input). You can see in the syntax highlighting that `input` is highlighted as a builtin (orange). I'd recommend using the attribute name instead, `num`.

Comment: On the other hand, it's only a problem if you intend to call the built-in function inside `System.__init__`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing

```
def getNum(self):
    return super().num
```

to

```
def getNum(self):
    return self.num
```

and see if that helps :)

Comment: This works because `super()` returns a proxy for the *class*, not the instance, so you are explicitly asking for the value of the class attribute shadowed by the instance attribute.

Answer (score 1):

`super()` explicitly calls the parent class and is used to access methods and objects that have been overwritten; ie, the exact opposite of what you want! As Capt. Trojan noted, `self.num` will get you the subclass version of `num` as you expect.

[Here](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) is the classic explaination of when and when not to use super.

Comment: There is no "subclass" version of `num`. It's an instance attribute, associated with the instance itself, without regard to which class's method might have created it (if, indeed, any method did).